# deep copy in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, deep-copy

I was working with Python deep copy trying to create a total copy of original object, but the deep copy didn't seem to create a copy. It still shares the same reference with original object, which is not desired

Here's the code. I have a `class Board`, the instance of which I want to deep copy.

```
import copy
class Board:
    xpos = None
    opos = None
    count = None
    status = []

    def __init__(self, size):
        self.xpos=[0,0]
        self.opos=[size-1,size-1]
        self.count = size*size-2
        for i in range(size):
            tmp = ['-']*size
            self.status.append(tmp)
        self.status[0][0] = 'X'
        self.status[size-1][size-1]= 'O'
```

Somewhere in another function I want to call

```
board=Board()
localboard=copy.deepcopy(board)
# then do modification to local board....
# but it seems the old board is also affected. This is so weird since
# I am already using deep copy.
```

So how can I create a deep copy of the old board? I don't want to share any reference, since I will do modification on the local one and want to keep the old intact..

Comment: This has nothing to do with deepcopy and everything with the mutable class attribute you gave your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the following from the `Board` definition:

```
xpos = None
opos = None
count = None
status = []
```

and add the following to its `__init__()`:

```
self.status = []
```

Otherwise all your instances share the same `status`, which is an attribute of the *class*, not of the *instance*.

Comment: Big thanks, I think it's the my fault of messing up with instance variable and class variable